# Searching for strings only partially works in x64Dbg

Tags: x64dbg

Please note that I am new to x64dbg.

As you can be seen in the picture below, the error message has the string

```
[ebp+8]:L"The information you have entered is invalid!\n..."
```

[image: address with string]

However, when I do
Search For > All Modules > String References, it does not pop up:

[image: no results found]

I am wondering why this searching only works for some strings, not all strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because a particular string is presented in your process memory during the execution of your program, it doesn't mean that it was prepared in advance (on disk) before you launch a program.

There are many other possibilities, how your program may load a "non-existing" string, for example:

- The string is combined (e.g. concatenated) from others,
- the string is entered by user,
- the string is created from its encrypted form,
- the string is from dynamically loaded DLL,
- the string is loaded from resources,
- the string is read from an external file,
- the string is loaded from an environmental variable,
- ... and so on.

Searching for a particular string is one of the simplest method in reverse engineering, but in the same time one of the *least reliable method*.

Comment: Great, thank you. How may I search a dynamically loaded string? As shown in my case above.

Comment: @MahmoudMaarouf, searching for dynamically loaded strings has no meaning, you will have no success with this method.